# Is there any github client for Windows

Tags: windows, github, client

Can someone advise any windows client for GitHub? 
I found the Tower client Mac (http://www.git-tower.com/) and seems it has very good integration with GitHub via API. Do you know any clients for windows with similar functionality?

**Update** Yes Thanks all for answers, I know about these three, but they only have integration with GIT, not GitHub. I mean some social features of GitHub, such as review of Incoming Request, comments for these Incoming Request, internal GitHub messaging support, possibility to create new repository on client, manage GitHub repository settings, and similiar features, subscribe to other repository and get notifications when they change. As I know, most of these feature available in GitHub API, but I can't found any windows client that use this API.

Comment: For all who found this, just to let you know tower-beta now released for windows, subscribe to beta here: https://www.git-tower.com/p/windows-beta

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GitHub for Windows ( after the popular GitHub for Mac ) with bundled [Posh-Git](http://windows.github.com/) ( powershell extension ) is also available - http://windows.github.com/

Atlassian's SourceTree is also coming soon to Windows - http://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/02/14/sourcetree-for-windows-beta-signup/

Comment: Two hours after launch of git for windows you found the question asked one year ago and replied. Great! OP came to accept as well :)

Comment: Yeah, answer with TortoiseGit by RemoteSojourner was good. But it's a little outdate. GitHub for Windows is really awesome and I changed my accept to this answer.

Comment: It has nice UI but missing a lot of features from its mac version.

Comment: @HP - Updated with a potential alternative.

Comment: After 100MB of downloads I could not log in. What a let down.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in this [blog post](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/10/2/smartgit-best-git-gui-so-far), **[SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html)** (free for *non-commercial* use) has an [integration with GitHub](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/features.html;jsessionid=BEC02772F1894B9C1F65A32E51CDE695#integration):

[image: Select from GitHub]

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseGit https://github.com/multitheftauto/multitheftauto/wiki/how-to-use-tortoisegit ?

Comment: Doesn't integrate with 'Github'.

Comment: TortoiseGit is buggy and crappy to start with Github. Not recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Just heard at [herding code](http://herdingcode.com/?p=384)  that the github guys are working on a new windows github specific client. In the meantime you can also try [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)  through power shell

Answer (score 2):

Github released a windows client today, find it at [windows.github.com](http://windows.github.com). It probably has the best integration with Github, and apparently makes git on windows easier.

Answer (score 0):

[msysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) and a [tutorial](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/)